# PHP Connection string

Tags: php, connection-string

Im having a few difficulties when connecting to a database using PHP. Im using the following code:

```
$db=mysql_connect ("HOST", "USER", "PASS") or die ('I cannot connect to the database because: ' . mysql_error());
```

and it works fine when connecting to a host using phpmyadmin. But my clients host is using something called mylittletools.net and for some reason the connection string will not access the database.

Its been racking my brain for days, I would really appreciate it if anyone could shed any light on this for me.

Comment: perhaps you meant `mysql_connect("$HOST","$USER","$PASS");` ?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: it could be as simple as thinking those are variables but forgetting the dollar sign (happens to people like me who still aren't used to PHP)

Comment: But you're better off listening to John's advice and dropping `mysql_*` functions...

Comment: Id double check and make sure you have the right hostname for your client

Comment: Quite weird. According to your code, your db is on mySQL.
Then you mention myLittleTools (myLittleAdmin) that is a web-based MS SQL admin tool.
Your DBMS is mySQL or MS SQL ?

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is correct, unless it is the variable problems as mentioned in comments the only explanations are that

- your server does not have MySQL server
- or PHP's MySQL driver is not working or not enabled.

Comment: Fully agree with John's Comment above, `mysql_*` are no longer cool.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't connect, because server refuses connection from other host.

When you create MySQL user - it has only access from local computer by default.

PHPMyAdmin connects to database from local machine, so it works.

If you want to connect from other server - you have to add permissions in MySQL for your mysql user.

You may add remote login privileges in PHPMyAdmin, or use SQL.

SQL example for specyfic IP 123.123.123.123

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES
ON database.*
TO 'user'@'123.123.123.123'
IDENTIFIED BY 'newpassword';
```

SQL example for any IP:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES
ON database.*
TO 'user'@'%'
IDENTIFIED BY 'newpassword';
```

Host `'%'` mean any host.